# How to get parameters values with the http_request cpprestsdk

Tags: c++, rest, httprequest

I like get only params of http_request as a json object and get each fields

My code apirest cpprestsdk

**void handle_get(http_request message){
cout<<"\n" << message.to_string() << "::::" << endl; **
....

**I try**: curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/cpprest/svrRest"  -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d "{"A":"a1","B":"b2"}"

**I obtain**:

GET /cpprest/svrRest HTTP/1.1
accept: */*
Content-Length: 19
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.88.1

**{"A":"a1","B":"b2"}::::**

I like params {"A":"a1","B":"b2"} as json object and get each fields.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.